# How do I run a nested query within a mongo shell forEach?

Tags: mongodb

I'm struggling to figure out how to run a query on every member of a collection in the mongo shell.  Here's what I've got so far.

```
rs0:SECONDARY> db.activity.find().limit(10).forEach(
...   function( activity ) {
...     var count = db['da-plan'].find( { activities: activity._id.toString() } ).count();
...     print(
...       "_id: "
...       + activity._id
...       + ", daPlanId: "
...       + activity.daPlanId
...       + ", count: "
...       + count);
...   }
... );
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d4697, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d4698, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d4699, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469a, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469b, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469c, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469d, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469e, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469f, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d46a0, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 0
rs0:SECONDARY> // for the first element at least, the count should not have been 0
rs0:SECONDARY> db['da-plan'].find( { activities: '5b045caf87207c00017d4697' } ).count();
1
```

My embedded query does not seem to be working as it always produces a count of zero but, when executed stand-alone, the count is usually non-zero.  What am I doing wrong?

How do you execute a nested query within a forEach loop in the mongo shell?

Comment: Try printing the query object in the loop to make sure it looks the way you expect.

Comment: @Joe that is helpful.  My `toString()` was definitely not doing what I thought it was doing.  `activities: activity._id.valueOf()` lets the rest of this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_id` is an `ObjectId` and not a String.  So `toString()`ing it didn't produce what the `count` query needs. Changing that to `activity._id.valueOf()` fixed the problem.

```
rs0:SECONDARY> db.activity.find().limit(10).forEach(
...   function( activity ) {
...     var count = db['da-plan'].find(
...       { activities: activity._id.valueOf() }
...     ).count();
...     print(
...       "_id: "
...       + activity._id
...       + ", daPlanId: "
...       + activity.daPlanId
...       + ", count: "
...       + count);
...   }
... );
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d4697, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d4698, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d4699, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469a, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469b, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469c, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469d, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469e, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d469f, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
_id: 5b045caf87207c00017d46a0, daPlanId: 5b045caf87207c00017d4694, count: 1
```